# Django how to create a post request for multiple forms.?

Tags: django-forms, django-views

i have multiple forms in the same template, each form is linked to a button(aform button , bform button.....)when clicked gets a pop up form with some fileds, how can i save that form by creating a post request in views.py

(i know to create a POST request for a single form.) but how do i achieve that for multiple forms.
NOTE: only one form can be submitted at a time.

def example_view(request):

```
context = {
    'aform':AForm(),
    'bform':BForm(),
    'cform':CForm(),
    'dform':DForm()
}
template = "xyz.html"
return render(request, template, context)
```

how do i create a post request for multiple forms?

Comment: Have you thought of using javascript/varieties?

Comment: I'm new to this, so I still have no idea how to use javascript/varieties to get POST request.

Comment: Whatever has been answered by Mr. Hasan id correct. To add to that: If you've 50 forms, do you mean you've 50 buttons? (Show 1 and hide 49 others). In that case, whichever button gets clicked, you read that from jquery/javascript & submit that to the necessary URL as shown by the answer. I suggest you try with some own codes, with the start-off provided by Mr. Hasan.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following ways.

1. Submit your form with ajax and handle each form separately. In this way, every form will be posted in different links.
2. Put different URLs in the action for the two forms. Then you'll have
   two different view functions to deal with the two different forms.
3. Read the submit button values from the POST data. You will have to send a parameter with which you can tell which
   submit button was clicked.

   ```
   forma = FormA(prefix="a")
   formb = FormB(prefix="b")
   which_form = request.GET.get('form_name')
   if request.POST:
        if which_form == 'a':
            forma = FormA(request.POST, prefix="a")
            if forma.is_valid():
                obja = forma.save()
        if which_form == 'b':
            formB = FormB(request.POST, prefix="b")
            if formb.is_valid():
                objb = formb.save()
   ```

Comment: I tried this approach, however I get a error.   ValueError at /
The view church.views.HomeView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been fighting with a similar situation.  I have a 'master' form which contains 3 'subsections' or 'subforms'. I thought of them as 4 forms for way too long. After searching a dozen SO posts.
I arrived at the following:

- In the html, use ONE  tag, which will POST to your view.  You can use  s or Bootstrap classes or whatever to make the HTML look like separate forms, but I only have/need one submit button.  In your example, place {{aform}}, {{bform}}, {{cform}} and {{dform}} inside the single  tag pair.
- In the view, while building aform, etc, assign a prefix to each form class (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms).  In fact, that same point in the documentation says outright "You can put several Django forms inside one  tag. To give each Form its own namespace, use the prefix keyword argument:"
- In the POST processor of your view, use the same prefixes.  This lets you resplit the combined POST data to aform, bform, cform and dform.